# Cant load log handler "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"

Tags: jenkins, webdriver, cucumber, tomcat7, build.gradle

I keep getting this error whenever i run my test in jenkins. I have downloaded the jar file to the lib folder but i still get the error. i have my dependencies defined in my local and i have provided the path. do i need to include the jar file in the dependencies as well? or How can i fix this ? Please help.

```
 [Gradle] - Launching build.
    [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\gradle-2.6\bin\gradle.bat cucumber && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
    Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.configure(JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:191)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:60)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:808)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:802)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(LogManager.java:1008)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.configure(JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:191)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:60)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.enter code hereloadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:808)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:802)
        at
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to jars which are not built properly or may be corrupted.

In my case the tomcat-juli.jar in Tomcat-Home/bin and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar in Tomcat-Home/lib are corrupted, So i replaced those with downloaded new jars.

In your case if you can refresh the dependencies it can work.....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dependency.

You need to define your dependency somewhere. It seems like you are using Gradle. Add the dependency that includes the class `org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` in your `dependencies` section in `build.gradle`.